# adding digital signature to PDF with visible timestamp and Reason field using ESIG/DSS

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pades

I am trying to understand and implement a solution based on European Commission-sponsored [Digital Signature Service project](https://github.com/esig/dss). I currently have succeeded in using the abstraction provided by the DSS-DEMO application, mentioned in the aforementioned github link, with the help of Nowina NexU client software. My wish is to digitally sign a PDF document with the following configuration:

- no container
- PAdES signature form
- enveloped
- PAdES_BASELINE_LT signature level
- SHA256 digest algorithm

I want the signature to have a visible part, i.e. to be seen on the first page of the document. This is somewhat demonstrated [here](https://dss.eidas.gov.gr/dss-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_pades_visible_signature). Personally, I need the actual signing timestamp and the name of the signer from her certificate. In the above demonstration this is done by providing "parameters" to the signing function.

I also want to fill the Reason field of the signature - it is then subsequently displayed when you view the Signature properties with a program like Adobe Acrobat Reader.

My problems so far are the following, and I can't seem to find neither examples nor other sort of information about them.

1. If I want to display the signing timestamp that I would get from a Timestamp Authority service, how would I get it, since the communication with the timestamp server is done during the signing process, i.e. after specifying the parameters as I mention above. I guess I have to dig into DSS code and do all the steps done there for me myself.
2. Currently, a strange thing happens. It appears that the signatures are deemed valid, or at least UNKNOWN, when I specify a hardcoded Reason (like 'testtest'), or no Reason at all. When I fill it from results of something else, the signature is not valid. Because things like this don't usually happen by magic, I must be doing something awfully wrong.

The code is organized approximately like this - there's a REST communication between two machines - a server and a client with NexU installed. NexU does all the communication with the smart card or any other certificate store on the client machine - it exchanges the digest value and the signed digest value with the server. There are, among others, two specific phases in the server code :

- getDataToSign - here a digest is calculated from the PDF content
- signDocument - here the actual signing - (embedding of the signature into the document, i guess?) takes place.

I am giving to both these phases a host of parameters, that, among other things, specify the signing timestamp, the Reason, and the visual parameters of the text I want to appear on the first page. I am doing this with the same parameters for both of the phases (because I am not sure on which phase I should give which)

My signing date - isn't it logical for it to be as close to the timestamp authority server's timestamp as can be? Okay - I am setting it to the current timestamp of my own server at the time of the beginning of the signing process.

I am setting Reason using PAdESSignatureParameters.setReason.
Any helpful insight is appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have solved the weird issue with the Reason field of the Signature.
2. I don't seem to see any way around the Signing Date being different from the Timestamping Authority-provided Timestamp.

Explanation follows.

As far as the first case, it was my fault. To elaborate, following my understanding, the signature parameters are provided to the DSS methods two times using SigningService.fillParameters() method.

1. in SigningService.getDataToSign(...) and then
2. in SigningService.signDocument(...)

This is important to be done in both methods, because during the first time, the hash/digest of the document-to-be-signed is calculated. Since I have chosen the signature to be enveloped, i.e. to be contained within the document that is going to be signed, we need to first apply the signature, and then calculate the digest basing on that "final" document.

As far as I saw in the DSS code (approximately), the in-memory representation of the uploaded PDF is signed, and its digest is calculated, during getDataToSign - but the outcome is discarded.

During the actual signDocument method (in between, the digest has travelled back to the client with NexU installed, and returned back to the server signed), the uploaded PDF is signed again, its digest calculated again, but this time the actual signed digest (we got from the client) is also applied to the document - and the in-memory outcome of this operation is sent back to the client as a signed PDF document.

What I was doing wrong is that during the first time, I was losing the variable that I was going to add as the Reason (it was lost somewhere in the model attributes - i was not passing it somewhere in between requests), with the result of my first map of parameters passed to getDataToSign differing from the second map of parameters - so it is only logical, that the actual hash/digest of the document was different from the digest in the saved signature (because at the time the digest-to-be-signed was calculated, i wasn't passing the Reason). That's why when I was passing a hardcoded value, because it was hardcoded, it was present during both calls to fillParameters. It was such a stupid mistake, I know. I should have known this because there was absolutely nothing about any difficulties with passing Reason (or other fields like Location) to the Signature.

BTW the signing is done using Apache PDFBox, and it is done incrementally.

As for the second thing, we decided to leave it as it is, although there is a comparatively impressive gap between the signing timestamp and the timestamp authority one. I don't really know what should be the allowed gaps in cases like this. I guess that this happens because

1. My server might have a slightly off-normal local time
2. Because the whole process of signing is going on between two machines (server and client with NexU installed, as well as the smart card), and because there are different dialog windows appearing asking for password etc. - it all postpones the actual signing and the call to the timestamping authority is done during the very last step. Of course, I am not sure if it is an issue, since theoretically timestamping authority doesn't know about the actual contents being changed - the previous error would have been triggered in that case..

That's more like it - of course I am open to other comments and answers. Thank you!